# How to show a Default view or simply a white screen when the NSPageController arrangedObjects count goes from one to zero?

Tags: macos

Mac App Using Xcode:7.3 on Sierra 10.12.2

I have a panel with a TabView that has a tab that enables adding and deleting photos. There is an NSPageController in Book mode which allows navigation of the photos. The arrangedObjects of the NSPageController are contained in a mutable array that supports the addition and deletion of photos. The pageController.view is an NSBox.

```
_editRecipeController.pageController.arrangedObjects = _mutPhotoImageArray;
```

I am writing to ask how I should handle the removal of the last remaining photo.

If the mutable array has more than one photo, when I click on the Delete button, the photo is removed from _mutPhotoImageArray, and the code navigates to one of the remaining photos in the pageController.

When I delete the final photo, I want the last photo to disappear and the 
header to say something like "No Photos Found"

What actually happens following the click on the Delete button when only one photo is in the PageController, is the photo does NOT disappear, so I am forced to display the rather kludgy message, "Press the Done Button to Delete the Final Photo."

How do I make the pageController display a blank screen?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to display no images, set arrangedObjects to ["empty"] (an array with a single object of any type/value except your normal data type).

In `pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any)`, guard on the object being of your data type. If it isn't, return an identifier of "empty".

In `pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String)`, if the identifier is "empty", return a view controller that displays your "no photos found" view.

I'm not sure if this is necessary, but in `pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, didTransitionTo object: Any)` if the object is "empty", I call my method to reset to an "empty" array. Not sure if necessary, but it doesn't hurt to have 1 extra guard there.

Comment: Mark Lilback, Thanks so very much for taking the time to answer! Great Info!